# Why the name static and dynamic in static and dynamic scoping

Tags: programming-languages, c

I am wondering, from where static and dynamic scoping got their names.

After understanding the concept of static and dynamic scoping in C, what I assume is that whenever we failed to find out the declaration of the variable within the scope of the function than in order to resolve this name, we refer the global variable (which is declared at the time of compilation). As name resolution of a variable is done by a global variable which is declared at the time of compilation (static), therefore this scoping is called static scoping.

On the other hand, if the name of a variable is resolved by a dynamic variable (variable created at runtime) than it is called dynamic scoping.

**Is this the reason why the static name is given to static scoping and dynamic to dynamic scoping?**

Comment: You have a 'nearly` complete misunderstanding of `static` and there is no variable modifier `dynamic`  Suggest reading the manual.  There are several different reasons to use the modifier `static`.  They all need to be understood when programng in C

Comment: I suggest you first ask "What is static and what is dynamic scoping of a variable?". (Note: C only has static scoping, what you are describing is incorrect understanding of C, as well as incorrect usage of terminology).